# Укороченные логические операции C++

Tags: c++, логические-выражения

```
  #include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
       using namespace std;
   
       
           bool A = -2 > 5;             // false
           bool B = 0 < 7;              // true
           bool C = 10 > 5 && 7 < 11;    // true
           bool D =  A && B || C;       // true
           std::cout << A << "\n";     // 0
           std::cout << B << "\n";     // 1
           std::cout << C << "\n";     // 1
           std::cout << D << "\n";     // 1
           return 0;
       
   }
```

Вопрос к выражению D. Укороченный логический оператор И(&&) позволяет перейти к ИЛИ  даже если у нас (A&&B)=false и потом в результате false || true получить true?

Comment: Приоритет приводит к (A && B) || C). A - false, значит, B не вычисляется, но так как (A && B) - false, С - вычисляется. Что тут непонятно?

Comment: Кажется, дошло. Вы прочли про сокращенное вычисление для `&&`, если первый операнд `false`, и ничтоже сумняшеся перенесли его на `||`? Мол, если первый `false`, то...? Так? Тогда учтите, что для `||` второй операнд не вычисляется, если первый - `true`.

Comment: Что значит "укороченый", в булевской алгебре есть "упрощение логического выражения" - соглашусь. Есть "бинарное и" и "булевское и" - у вас булевское. "Укороченое" - непоняно. Булевское от бинароного отличается тем, что бинарное - оперирует с всеми нулями и еденицами которое есть в расчётных данных (для байта 8 для int 32-битного 32), а булевское оперирует только 0 и 1, и любое входящее число отличное от 0 считается 1.

Comment: @nick_n_a Имеется в виду short circuit evaluation - см., например, https://ravesli.com/urok-43-logicheskie-operatory-i-ili-ne/#toc-4